# JSF t:dataList the getter for the value is called before the action listener method

Tags: jsf, actionlistener, jsf-1.2

I have a JSF (1.2) with the following:

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{fn:length(testBeanToDelete.names) gt 0}">
    <t:dataList value="#{testBeanToDelete.names}" var="name" rowIndexVar="index">
        <p>#{name}</p>
    </t:dataList>
</h:outputText>
<h:form id="test_form">
    <h:commandLink value="Filter" actionListener="#{testBeanToDelete.filter}"/>
</h:form>
```

My problem is that when I click on the filter button the getNames() method is called before the event method filter.
In the getNames() method I check whether name == null and then I create the list.

But, I want in case the filter method is called to create a new filtered list (basically I want to get from the DB different filtered values), but I don't want to to call the DB twice.

How can I achieve this goal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the JSF lifecycle, the first thing that is done is rebuilding the page in the restore view phase. The point here is to rebuild the page as it was in the last request. Here getNames() is called.

Later, at the end of the JSF lifecycle in the render response phase, getNames() will be called again for the values of the new page.

The only way to avoid a DB call in the restore view phase is to have the collection for the dataList you returned in your last request saved. Your backing bean needs to have a **scope higher than request or you'll need to save them between requests somehow**. This is not trivial and can lead to problems of excessive use of RAM in the server if handled incorrectly, so be careful.

Are you using Trinidad? Then the solution could be to save the collection for the datalist in the [page flow scope](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/communicatingBetweenPages.html#pageFlowScope). Still, think about if avoiding that database call is worth all this.

Comment: Hi, I am actually using tomahawk which has the saveState solution, I can try using it for my flow. Thank you very much for your help.